# Find each occurrence of n different sequence of characters in a list of m characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pattern-matching

As an example :

I have 3 lists -

seq_to_find = ['abc','de']  *(length = n)*

main_list= [**'a','b','c'**,'ghi',**'d','e',**'far','last',**'a','b','c'**] *(length = m)*

transaction_nums=[1,3,6,8,10,15,16,17,19,20,22] *(note: always sorted,length = m)*

how do I find the starting and ending index numbers of each sequence that occurs in the main_list.

In other words I want to write a function, Say

```
def findTheMasks(seq_to_find,main_list,transaction_nums):

    returns a list with sublists having "start" and "end" transaction_nums
```

for the example given above : [[1,6][10,15][19,22]]

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if a,b & c are not consecutive?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, or tutorial service.  We'll happily help you with your programming attempt, but simply handing us your homework without showing your own serious attempt, isn't playing fair.

Comment: what if main_list include `['ab', 'c']`, does that count?

Comment: what should be the result for this seq_to_find `['abc', 'fara', 'gh']` ?

Comment: while processing  main_list  elements are considered( as it is) ,  seq_to_find elements are considered character wise.  i.e in main list ["ab" , "c"] means 2 elements . but in seq_to_find ['ab'] means  a pattern where a is followed by b as next element.  From the data I am processing ,we can assume that each seq_to_find element is to be considered a sequence of characters. @Prune , This is a part of my feature extraction I was doing on a pandas data frame. Thank you in advance. Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that partially matched sequence does not go into result. And I also assume there is no empty (`''`) seq. Here is a sample solution.

```
seq_to_find = ['abc', 'de']
main_list= ['a','b','c','ghi','d','e','far','last','a','b','c'] 
transaction_nums=[1,3,6,8,10,15,16,17,19,20,22]

def findTheMasks(seq_to_find,main_list,transaction_nums):
    ret = []

    # go through each in main list
    for i in range(0, len(main_list)):
        # try to match each seq
        for seq in seq_to_find:
            remain = seq

            # match seq from start, reduce seq if any match, until empty
            for j in range(i, len(main_list)):
                x = main_list[j]

                # remain matches next in main list
                if remain.startswith(x):
                    remain = remain.replace(x, '', 1)
                    # everything matched
                    if not remain:
                        break
                # not matched
                else:
                    break

            # fully matched, add to result
            if not remain:
                ret.append([transaction_nums[i], transaction_nums[j]])
    return ret

print(findTheMasks(seq_to_find, main_list, transaction_nums))
```

And output is:

```
[[1, 6], [10, 15], [19, 22]]
```

Comment: Thank you!!! worked like a charm. The assumption is correct. partially matched sequence was supposed to be ignored. Thanks